# how to modify laravel middleware to work with firebase authentication

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, firebase-authentication

I am working in laravel and firebase as a backend for authentication and data storage. I am using firebase provided js code to signin the user

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
```

The problem is that I want to protect my routes from non-authenticated users. How would I check this in my middleware that user is logged in or not because js stores current user's uid in localStorage. Do I have to use a separate database for this purpose? Please help me to go in right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to call:

```
 auth.currentUser.getIdToken().then(function(token) {
   // The Firebase id token is returned here.
   // You will have to send that along your requests to your server.
   // Keep in mind this is a short lived token
   // You have to call getToken each time you need it in case
   // it is auto refreshed underneath.
 });
```

Currently, Firebase provides node.js and java backend libraries to verify the token (to check the user is logged in). 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server

A php library is in the works. When it is ready, it should provide similar functionality for minting custom tokens and verifying Firebase id tokens.

Comment: I want to check in my middleware if the user is logged in or not to protect my app routes. I am getting user information from localStorage and storing it in cookies and then reading the cookie in my middleware, is this a safe approach?

Comment: Even if you read the cookie in your middleware, you still need to validate the token. I suggest for now only storing the Firebase Id token obtained above in a cookie. In the near future you will be able to validate that using the php library when it's ready. The localStorage contains some sensitive data like the refresh token which should not be sent to the backend as it does not expire unless big account changes occur and you do not want to risk it being leaked. Make sure your site is encrypted via https and set the secure flag for your cookie.

Comment: Also keep in mind the id token expires every hour, so you have to update the cookie value every time it is refreshed. The firebase team is working on a php library short term and in addition a better solution for session management which will help your case.

Comment: For people reading this a bit later, it's now: auth.currentUser.get`Id`Token().then(function(token)

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use this https://github.com/vinkas0/firebase-auth-laravel laravel package to authenticate via firebase